# How do JMS transactions work with concurrent consumers?

Tags: java, jms, ibm-mq, messaging

I have a queue of messages which need sequential processing. Now this processing involves calling a Web service (which might be down sometimes) so I have to make the message retrieval transactional. As far as I know, when there's any exception midway, the whole transaction rolls back and the message isn't lost right?

But what's also needed is high availability (HA) on the message consumer, so I have two instances of the listener listening in on my queue. Now will the transaction ensure that a second message isn't retrieved by the other instance of the listener until the first one is completely done processing the first message? Or will I have to do something more to make sure that no message is sent out of the queue until the one before that is fully done processing.

If any additional configuration is needed, would it be in the MQ or on the listener?

---

I'm using [WebSphere MQ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_MQ) as the message broker and [Spring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spring_Framework) integration for retrieving the messages.

With the token thing, the first concern would be high availability on the queue manager itself. The queue which holds this token has to be part of some queue manager. Now, if we have a failover, that controls the queue will no longer be accessible. Which kind of means that that we need another control queue ready in case of a failover.

We can't have listeners listening in on that DR control queue during normal operations though. (Let's say we have a mechanism to actually make sure that the "data" queue is perfectly replicated). The listener instances should know that a failover has been initiated, so that it can stop listening to the control queue during normal operations and switch over to the secondary. I can't do this using the listener instance alone. The actual producer which puts messages into the queue will have to notify the listener instances to stop listening to the normal operations control queue and switch over to the secondary.

This would be kind of tricky if there's any intermediate connection problem (and the normal operations queue manager isn't really down), but that's too much of a corner case.

With high availability of the control queue taken care of, we kind of have the same problem as the nonsharable setting during low load scenarios. Now we have occasional spikes in load, but there are slump periods (during the night and stuff). This token system is not really reactive, right? It's more of periodic thing. So let's say we don't get any messages for a few hours. The listeners will still be constantly checking the queue because the token message keeps triggering one instance after another. Which more or less makes it a poller, really. I might as well have multiple listener instances each polling at like different times of the hour, right? It's not really event driven per se.

Third would really be the question of inserting the token message. During first install or during a failback, we'll have that extra manual step of manually inserting this token (since the token would be lost in failover sometimes). We can't really make one of the listener instances do it since if a listener instance doesn't find the message it kind of means that some other listener instance has the token. So this logic has to be separate. And if we actually put some meaningful information into this token message, it has to be a utility that has to be triggered rather than an insertion through the UI.

I guess the first and third aren't really problems, but just extra overhead which wouldn't be needed if we went for a poller implementation. The second one is what's bothering me most.

Comment: It is incomprehensible near *"if we have a failover, that controls the queue will no longer be accessible"*. Can you [fix it](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/33637289/edit)? But *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***[without](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/131011)*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the question should appear as if it was written today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be passing tokens.  Here's how that works:

First, create a second queue and place a single message into it.  Now start up each program with the following logic.

1. Get the token message off the token queue under syncpoint using an unlimited or long wait interval and the `FAIL_IF_QUIESCING` option.
2. Put the token message back on the token queue in the same [UOW](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/was/8.5.5?topic=SSEQTP_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.javadoc.doc/web/spidocs/com/ibm/wsspi/uow/UOWManager.html).
3. Get the next message off of the application queue under the same UOW.
4. Process the application's message normally.
5. Commit the UOW.

You can use as many application instances as you want.  You will see one input handle on each of the two queues for each application instance.  No application instance will have to handle errors due to exclusive use of a queue.

Since there is only one token message and only one application can hold it under syncpoint at a time, only one of the applications can be actively processing an application message.  Since the `GET` off the application queue is dependent on a successful `GET` off the token queue, all application messages are processed in strict sequence.

*Note: The application will process the application messages with as many concurrent threads as there are token messages on the token queue.  If anyone ever adds another token message to the token queue, strict sequence processing is lost.  For this reason read/write access to that queue must *not* be granted to anyone other than the application service account.  Also, it is common for that token message to be structured so that the application can recognize it.  If a stray unrelated message lands there the application should ignore it and throw a warning.*

You will see a fairly even distribution of messages between the two applications.  If you use more than two applications you might see a wildly *un*even distribution because queue handles are managed in a stack. As an instance commits its UOW the next instance's handle is at the top of the stack so it gets the next message.  While it is handling that message the instance that just committed will have it's `GET` placed on top of the stack.  If you have 3 or more listening instances chances are only the first two will see any traffic.

This assures that messages are processed off the queue one at a time.  It does ***not*** assure that you won't get dupes.

If you do everything under syncpoint, no messages will ever be lost.  However there's a scenario in which a message is retrieved and processed, then the `COMMIT` call fails.  In that case the transaction is rolled back and the same message becomes available again.  If you are using 1-phase commits and not [XA](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/9.1?topic=registration-summarizing-xa-calls), the processing for that message will not be rolled back.

The nice thing is that the token message will be under syncpoint too and that fixes the issue in which an orphaned client channel takes a while to release the transaction.  A new connection will get messages which are older than the message held under syncpoint by the orphan transaction.  Eventually the channel agent times out releasing the message back to the queue but effectively changing its position to be *behind* any messages that were processed while it was sequestered.

In this scenario the token message is also sequestered so after this type of connection loss message processing temporarily stops and waits for the channel agent to time out.  If that were ever to happen, just issue a `STOP CHANNEL` command on the instance with the UOW.

---

***Update based on additional question details specific to this answer***

> The queue which holds this token has to be part of some queue manager.
> Now if we have a failover, that control queue will no longer be
> accessible. Which kinda means that that we need another control queue
> ready in case of a failover.

The token queue is as available or as unavailable as the application queue. Only one is needed.  If the application requires high availability (HA), then a Multi-Instance QMgr or a hardware high availability cluster should be used.  These share disk so the QMgr that comes up in the failover is the same one the application has been connected to, just at a different physical location.

If the application needs [DR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disaster_recovery), it's possible to replicate the disk under the QMgr's logs and data directories to a DR site.  However, nothing should be listening on those instances while processing is going on in the primary data center.

> The listener instances should know that a failover has initiated so
> that it can stop listening to the control queue during normal ops and
> switch over to the secondary. I can't do this using the listener
> instance alone.

Why not? WebSphere MQ has had reconnectable clients for a really long time and the multi-instance features in v7.0.1 made reconnecting drop-dead simple.  As an administrator, your job is to make sure that no more than one instance of the application and token (not trigger!) queue are available.  During an outage, the client goes into retry without requiring any application code to drive it.  It finds whichever of the instances is up and connects.

> The actual producer which puts messages into the queue will have to
> notify the listener instances to stop listening to the normal ops
> control queue and switch over to the secondary.

The question was about serialization with concurrent consumers.  This is about a design in which producers and consumers have to rendezvous at a common location. Different problem that happens to overlap this one only in that it is complicated somewhat by serialization. Ask a different question if you need to explore topologies.

> This token system is not really
> reactive right? It's more of periodic thing. So let's say we don't get
> any messages for a few hours. The listeners will still be constantly
> checking the queue coz the token message keeps triggering one instance
> after another.

This does not use triggering. It uses a token (not trigger!) message the way a filesystem or database uses a lock in order to facilitate serialization. Whichever listener gets the token message then does a get with unlimited wait on the application queue.  The other listeners have a get with unlimited wait on the token (not trigger!) queue. Basically, they sit around idle until a message arrives.  Zero reconnections, zero polls, zero CPU cycles.  If you need to know they are alive, let them time out on the application queue once in a while.  This rolls back their UOW on the token queue which passes the token to another listener.

> Third would really be the question of inserting the token message.
> During first install or during a failback, we'll have that extra
> manual step of manually inserting this token (since the token would be
> lost in failover sometimes).

Why? Do you experience MQ losing persistent messages under syncpoint often? If so you are doing it wrong. ;-) In a situation with strict serialization requirements there can be only one active instance of a queue. If for some reason there are other instances of the application queue pre-defined other than through disk replication there would be one instance of the token (not trigger!) queue also predefined alongside it and one token (not trigger!) message waiting in each queue. Surely nobody would do such a thing in the face of strict message order requirements, but if they did those queues would surely be get-disabled while not in use.

> We can't really make one of the listener
> instances do it since if a listener instance doesn't find the message
> it kinda means that some other listener instance has the token.

Correct. The listeners *could* check queue depth, transactions, input handles, etc, but it is generally wise to avoid mixing application logic with control logic.

> So
> this logic has to be separate. And if we actually put some meaningful
> info into this token message, it has to be a utility that has to be
> triggered rather than an insertion through the UI.

Why? Your coders handle structured data in application messages, right? If this is perceived to be significantly more difficult, someone's doing it wrong. ;-)  Write an instance of a formatted token (not trigger!) message to a queue, then offload that to a file. When you need to reinitialize the queue, use Q or QLoad to first clear the queue, then load the file into it. **That** utility would be the one to open the queue for exclusive use, check for depth, check for handles, etc. prior to performing its magic.  When I do this for consulting clients I typically define a service that initializes the queue on MQ startup *and* also provide a feature in the application GUI for the operations and support staff.  So long as the application managing the token (not trigger) queue gets it for exclusive access during these operations it really doesn't matter how it's done or by how many instances of the control application.

As a rule I also use the structure in the message to send commands to the listeners.  There's the real token message, and then there's messages that command the application instances to do things. For example, it's really nice to have a non-transactional "ping" capability. I if I drop more ping messages on the token (not trigger!) queue in a single UOW than I have application instances listening, I am guaranteed to contact all of them. In this way I can detect zombies.  Depending on how much instrumentation is required the listeners can react to the ping by providing a status (uptime, messages processed, etc.) in the log, to the console, to an event queue, etc.

> I guess the first and third aren't really problems, but just extra
> overhead which wouldn't be needed if we went for a poller
> implementation.

That's good because this is all pretty standard stuff. The problem lies mainly with the requirements for serialization conflicting with those for HA/DR. What you are looking for is global transactional atomicity to implement a single logical queue across multiple physical locations.  IBM MQ has never attempted to provide that, although the [WebSphere Application Server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_WebSphere_Application_Server) (WAS) Messaging Engine has.  The closest IBM MQ comes is to use two IBM MQ appliances with memory-to-memory replication of message and transaction data but that is good to only a few miles before light-speed latency begins to significantly impact throughput. It doesn't handle your DR needs.  In fact, *nothing* short of synchronous replication does that if you want a zero recovery point at the DR datacenter.

Comment: Hey so the token is kinda used to lock any other concurrent consumers from accessing the actual "data" queue when another instance is feeding off of it right? I saw your answer in http://stackoverflow.com/a/18902573/2885370 and that's what we're more or less going for (a little extra tweak of using an Initiation queue instead of this control queue was applied) , but there are a few other problems. I'll edit my question with details.

Comment: I'm trying to wrap my head around mixing triggering with this approach. I can't imagine how or why an initiation queue would be used for this. Part of the problem is alluded to in your comments about the producer/consumer rendezvous. It sounds like you are mixing topology solutions with serialization solutions and these overlap a bit but are generally separate issues.  Many of my clients are using tokens for serialization with great success. None have mixed it with triggering to my knowledge.

Comment: Ooh so one instance gets the token and does a receive without timing out at all. I didn't get that the first time. Awesome thanks. The producer notifying the listener is something we're doing coz I had no idea how to get the listeners to switch from one queue to the other. I'll try to understand all the other stuff you've said and come back with any clarifications. Thanks a lot. :-)

Comment: With triggering what we're doing is setting it up so that the Initiation queue gets a message when a first message lands on the data queue. One of the competing consumers takes it and processes the data queue till it's empty. I'm still using the producers to notify me about a queue manager being down, and when it does the listeners are unhooked from the primary Initiation queue and hooked onto the secondary which uses the same trigger mechanism. (I'm using a control bus to achieve this programmatically. I'll have to check out the reconnectable clients. I'm like a total noob to MQ)

Comment: Good luck! Be sure to click the [tag:websphere-mq] tag and check out the "getting started" resources. I try to keep an eye on the tag here but if a question goes unanswered feel free to ping me. Contact info is in the profile.

Comment: Will do thanks. Oh and in your original answer, putting the token message back would be like the final step right? Not right after we pick the token message? We get the message off of the application queue and then put the token back? Or will the new token not be available to the other listener instances till the commit happens, which means it can be put back any time after the initial retrieval?

Comment: It's all under the same UOW so the token won't be available to the next app until the `COMMIT` regardless of when it is put. There are lots of good reasons to put the token message immediately but the top ones are that doing so keeps the queue depth at 1 most of the time. Doing at after the app message is processed makes the token queue look empty most of the time. Another reason is that is all token operations happen at the same time it can be contained in an include file. This ensures all apps using the technique use the same logic and avoid deadly embraces.

Answer (score 0):

On your high availability question...

If you've got two queue receivers reading from a single queue, I don't know any natural way to avoid parallelism between them.

Maybe some vendor-specific feature, but it seems like an odd thing and I wouldn't have any high expectations.

Answer (score 0):

If you process the messages under syncpoint, it is true that you can roll back the transactions so putting the processed message back to the input queue in case an error occurs.
If the program ends abnormally, an implicit backout occurs.

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_7.5.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q026800_.htm?lang=en

Transactional processing of messages doesn't prevent two separate consumers from reading messages at the same time.
There is a property on the queues called Shareability, which can be set to Not Shareable so preventing the queue to be opened by separate consumers at the same time.
You should use this option and prepare your application to retry opening the queue so when the first instance fails, the second instance will open the queue.

Comment: Yeah i did try the non shareable option, but once one of the listeners hooks on, the other listeners won't be able to right? I don't really want the second listener to keep erroring out and trying to latch itself onto the queue in a loop. If the first listener goes down, there's no real way for me to notify the second listener so it can go start listening either.

Comment: What is the argument against having the 2nd listener erroring and retrying?

Comment: Well it's not very clean right? The very idea of an "exception" is that something has gone wrong. But here, it's the exact opposite. Until the 2nd listener keeps getting exceptions, the system is in normal ops (nothing wrong) . When the exception stops, it means we're in failover (something's wrong). Even from a pure performance perspective, it's taking up lots of memory. I have this other component on the same WAS that actually puts the messages into these queues. I noticed a considerable performance dip if one of the listeners was constantly trying attach and failing.

Comment: I dunno if there's any way to periodically try to latch onto a queue, but even if there was, that would mean it's no better than a poller really. We need to be kinda consistent with our SLA. Saying that message processing might be slower on failover would mean we're not consistent. :(

Comment: Using the given architecture and restrictions I cannot see any other solution. I think you will need some way to send heartbeats between your consumer applications or some other way to keep 1 and only 1 instance up, MQ alone cannot really solve this.